# Android Studio For each Macro

Tags: android, eclipse, foreach, android-studio

On eclipse, when I write `for` I get a macro option on autosuggestion to implement a foreach with any list that I Have. Have any way of do it on Android studio? because when I write `for`on android studio I get only the traditional for and methods on autosuggestion box.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Android Studio has really nice live templates that come from IntelliJ. On Mac the default keybinding is command-J, but if you're not on Mac, then search your keybindings for *Insert live template...*

After you press the key combo to start inserting a live template, it gives you a list of templates on the screen and you can start typing to choose a template from the list. If I want to iterate over a `Iterable`, I press <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> followed by <kbd>i</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>. It's pretty smart about reading the context and choosing likely defaults for what I want to iterate over, but it has on-screen prompts that let you enter the parameters for the template.

See https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/live-templates.html for more info.

Comment: Cmd-J is so useful! I can't believe I'm just learning about it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

Android Studio do it in a different way :

you can use following 'live templates' to generate several types of code snippets for loop iteration :

```
iter    Iterate using foreach loop 
itli    Iterate over a List using normal for loop
itar    Iterate elements of array using normal for loop
ritar   Iterate elements of array in reverse order using normal for loop
```

Enter any of the above keyword in Android Studio and press Tab key, Studio will generate template for you .

`Ctrl+J` will give you all available templates in windows.

There are probably many more, just lookup 'Live Templates' in help documentation of Intellij Idea.

Comment: Great that it helped you :)

Answer (score 6):

This is already available in Android Studio, known as Live Template.
You can have a look at the predefined in Preferences -> Live Templates.
There is also on for a foreach loop, just type:

`iter` and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, but the answer of scott is most complete, and ctrl not works for me because i'm mac and the keys in my case is cmd. any way thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok, don't know about Mac as a Linux user :-)

Comment: :D I`m a linux user too, but I'm on mac today temporarily :/.

Comment: You can also set the keybinding to Eclipse and have nice tab+tab picking instead of ctr+j.